# How can I list/add Nodes to my Pylon App from python command line?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pylons

I have a Pylons application that I inherited. It has a MySQL database. There is a Model called Node in the applicaiton. I want to first list all the Nodes in the database. Then, I'd like to be able to add a node. So far, I have been trying:

```
import myapp.model as model
nodes = model.Session.query(model.Node).all()
for node in nodes:
    print node
```

The above code throws an error which I have seen in other questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445772/sqlalchemy-exc-unboundexecutionerror-could-not-locate-a-bind-configured-on-mapp):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1579, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1689, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1694, in _execute_and_instances
    mapper=self._mapper_zero_or_none())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 717, in execute
    engine = self.get_bind(mapper, clause=clause, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 851, in get_bind
    raise sa_exc.UnboundExecutionError(
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|Node|node, SQL expression or this Session
```

I feel like I am missing a step or something. I'm accustom to working with models in Django and this is my first time working with a Pylon application. I think that this has something to do with Sessions but I'm not sure. Does anyone know how I could list all the Nodes and then add a Node?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out was was wrong. I never set up a session with my database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import myapp.model as model

engine = create_engine("mysql://username:password@localhost/myapp")
conn = engine.connect()
session = Session(bind=conn)
nodes = session.query(model.Node).all()
for node in nodes:
    print node
```