# Why am I getting 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute'?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This code works fine:

```
Base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker()
Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class MatchesATP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "matches_atp"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "belgarath",
                      "extend_existing": True}

    ID_M = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ID_T_M = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.tours_atp.ID_T"))


query = session.query(MatchesATP)
print([result for result in query])
```

I'm now trying to build an access layer:

```
class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/"
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = sessionmaker()
        self.session = Session()
```

I create it using:

```
dal = DataAccessLayer()
```

And then try to run the query:

```
query = dal.session.query(MatchesATP)
print([result for result in query])
```

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Philip/OneDrive/Betting/Capra/Tennis/polgara/db_interface_orm_so.py", line 34, in <module>
    print([result for result in query])
  File "C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\polgara\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3481, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\polgara\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3503, in _execute_and_instances
    querycontext, self._connection_from_session, close_with_result=True
  File "C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\polgara\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3518, in _get_bind_args
    mapper=self._bind_mapper(), clause=querycontext.statement, **kw
  File "C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\polgara\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3496, in _connection_from_session
    conn = self.session.connection(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\polgara\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1136, in connection
    bind = self.get_bind(mapper, clause=clause, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\polgara\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1577, in get_bind
    % (", ".join(context))
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper mapped class MatchesATP->matches_atp, SQL expression or this Session
```

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18447217/11277108) suggests replacing:

```
self.session = Session()
```

With:

```
self.session = Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
```

However, doing that I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Philip/OneDrive/Betting/Capra/Tennis/polgara/db_interface_orm_so.py", line 32, in <module>
    query = dal.session.query(MatchesATP)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Any ideas on where I can go from here?

Comment: The linked answer is a bit off in that `Session.configure()` mutates `Session` itself, and in Python it is common for such self mutating methods to return `None`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: To add to the previous, the end result is that `dal.session` is `None`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - thanks for responding. How do I build the DAL so I can query the database without getting either of the errors?

Comment: @furas - I've added in the full statements

Comment: Evaluate `Session.configure(...)` before and separately from `self.session = Session()`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Worked like a charm. Happy to accept that as the answer...